# Sorting table based on Year and Year+Months

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a table with a column Year and ID

```
YEAR              ID
1988                29
1989                 89
1990                22
1992                9
1994                8
1998                23
1922                 20
August 1990          12
September 2009         14
August 1991            11
November 2009           33
October 1990            30
January 1990            55
March 2001              24
```

Is there way I can sort the table in such a way that my final result is in Order.. I am looking for the result like

```
YEAR              ID
1922                20
1988                29
1989                 89
1990                22
1992                9
1994                8
1998                23
January 1990            55
August 1990          12
October 1990            30
August 1991            11
March 2001              24
September 2009         14
November 2009           33
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `myYear` with your table name...

```
select year,id
from
(select year,id,
case when STR_TO_DATE(year,'%Y') is not null then STR_TO_DATE(year,'%Y') else STR_TO_DATE(year,'%M %Y') end as d,
case when STR_TO_DATE(year,'%Y') is not null then 0 else 1 end as ob
from myYear
) y
order by ob asc,d asc;
```